# Writing a query using like with python and mysql connector

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, wildcard

How do you write a query using like with the mysql connector and python. I am trying to avoid sql injections and using an ORM is not an option.

```
       param = 'bob'
       select_query = mysql_conn.query_db("select * from table_one where col_name like '%?%' order by id asc limit 5", param)
```

No matter what I send in when the query gets executed I get the same results. I should be getting nothing.

When I use the below query I get an error.

```
        select_query = mysql_conn.query_db("select * from table_one where col_name like %s order by id asc limit 5", param)
```

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s order by id asc limit 5' at line 1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the `%` wildcards to the `param` you're passing before escaping, e.g like this:

```
select_query = mysql_conn.query_db(
    "select * from table_one where col_name like %s order by id asc limit 5",
     ("%{}%".format(param),)
)
```

Also the parameters should be passed as a tuple like above, or as a dict when using named parameters:

```
select_query = mysql_conn.query_db(
    "select * from table_one where col_name like %(p)s order by id asc limit 5",
     {"p": "%{}%".format(param)}
)
```

Comment: That worked.  Thanks.  I do have another question.  I set the param as a tuple then send the query and the tuple to my connection class.  But that fails?  I have to set the param as a tuple in the connection class.

Comment: param = (request.form['txt'],)
on my connection class
    <class 'tuple'>
    class get_connectioned():
        def query_db(self, query, param):
            self.curr.execute(query, (param)
            return self.curr
The above fails.  But if I do the following it works.
    param = request.form['txt']
    <class 'str'>
    class get_connectioned():
        def query_db(self, query, param):
            self.curr.execute(query, ("%{}%".format(param),))
            return self.curr
Why does making the param a tuple in the class work. Yet sending the param in as a tuple fails?

Comment: @user3525290 it's hard to say with the code like this in a comment. It should do approximately the same, except that the first one uses the parameter as is while the second encloses it in wildcards..

Answer (score 1):

> Note that any literal percent signs in the query string passed to
>   execute() must be escaped, i.e. %%

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Which is pretty much the same thing as in old style python string formatting, c printf etc etc

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add the % wildcards to the param you're passing before escaping, e.g like this:
>
> select_query = mysql_conn.query_db(
> "select * from table_one where col_name like %s order by id asc limit 5",
> ("%{}%".format(param),)
> )

Threw me an error arror a la

> TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'tuple'

so what worked for me was explicitly coding the quotations marks into the selection quote like this:

```
  "select * from table_one where col_name like \"%"+param+"%\" order by id asc limit 5"
```